# Repeating prints on backtracking/recursion algorithm:

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, backtracking

I am studying a backtracking solution, but I don’t understand why a print is repeating inside the loop. It does not seem instantiated by the recursive function or the loop. I think it will be explained better by the code (leave here the source link as well://leetcode.com/problems/subsets/discuss/2739067/PythonJavaJSC++-by-DFS-backtracking-w-Demo).

```
class Solution:
def subsets(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
    
    
    all_subset = []
    bag = []
    
    
    def makeSubsetFrom( startIndex ):
        
        # Add current subset into final result
        # Note: python object is passing by reference, so we have to make a copy
        all_subset.append( bag[::] )
        print("Recursion starts: ", startIndex)
        
        ## Base cases aka stop condition:
        # No more element
        if startIndex == len(nums):
            print("EQUAL return blank")
            return
        
        ## General cases
        # Current level, we choouse element on index i
        for i in range(startIndex, len(nums) ):
            print("Loop runs - INDEX; ", i)
            print("Subset: ", startIndex , all_subset)
            bag.append( nums[i] )           # put this element into bag
            print("BAG1: ", bag, i)
            makeSubsetFrom( i+1 )           # make subset from remaining elements
            print("BAG2: ", bag, i)
            bag.pop()                       # undo selection
        
        return
    
    #----------------------------------------
    makeSubsetFrom( startIndex = 0 )
```

Console output:

```
Recursion starts:  0
Loop runs - INDEX;  0
Subset:  0 [[]]
BAG1:  [1] 0
Recursion starts:  1
Loop runs - INDEX;  1
Subset:  1 [[], [1]]
BAG1:  [1, 2] 1
Recursion starts:  2
Loop runs - INDEX;  2
Subset:  2 [[], [1], [1, 2]]
BAG1:  [1, 2, 3] 2
Recursion starts:  3
EQUAL return blank
BAG2:  [1, 2, 3] 2
BAG2:  [1, 2] 1 -> **Where does this second output comes from? It does not seem to start either by the loop or the recursion** 
Loop runs - INDEX;  2
```

Answer (score 1):

The second BAG2 goes with the second BAG1.  Try adding indentation to your output so you can see which level of recursion each is happening at:

```
from typing import List

def subsets(nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
    all_subset = []
    bag = []
    
    
    def makeSubsetFrom( startIndex ):
        indent = startIndex * 4 * " "
        # Add current subset into final result
        # Note: python object is passing by reference, so we have to make a copy
        all_subset.append( bag[::] )
        print(indent + "Recursion starts: ", startIndex)
        
        ## Base cases aka stop condition:
        # No more element
        if startIndex == len(nums):
            print(indent + "EQUAL return blank")
            return
        
        ## General cases
        # Current level, we choouse element on index i
        for i in range(startIndex, len(nums) ):
            print(indent + "Loop runs - INDEX; ", i)
            print(indent + "Subset: ", startIndex , all_subset)
            bag.append( nums[i] )           # put this element into bag
            print(indent + "BAG1: ", bag, i)
            makeSubsetFrom( i+1 )           # make subset from remaining elements
            print(indent + "BAG2: ", bag, i)
            bag.pop()                       # undo selection
        
        return
    
    #----------------------------------------
    makeSubsetFrom( startIndex = 0 )

subsets([1, 2])
```

prints:

```
Recursion starts:  0
Loop runs - INDEX;  0
Subset:  0 [[]]
BAG1:  [1] 0
    Recursion starts:  1
    Loop runs - INDEX;  1
    Subset:  1 [[], [1]]
    BAG1:  [1, 2] 1
        Recursion starts:  2
        EQUAL return blank
    BAG2:  [1, 2] 1
BAG2:  [1] 0
Loop runs - INDEX;  1
Subset:  0 [[], [1], [1, 2]]
BAG1:  [2] 1
        Recursion starts:  2
        EQUAL return blank
BAG2:  [2] 1
```

Note that now the BAG1 and BAG2 that happen in the same loop are horizontally aligned, whereas the ones that happen inside a recursion are indented down a level so you can more easily tell them apart.